# How can I create my custom palette in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I'am starting a project on which we want to study the information process flow inside the company I work with. I have to create different agent-type that represents the different **departments** and the **information** exchanged between them.

To maintain the project ordered I would like to know if it is possible, and if yes how, creating palette that will host my agent-type. I would like to create a palette "departments" and "information".

Thanks Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the AnyLogic help first. Open it (Help/AnyLogic Help/) and search for "Creating a library", all details are there for you.
To be able to export the library (for other users to use it), you will need the Prof license, though.

Comment: thanks...it was some days that I search the wrong thing :)